# Import ACCDB file of Access DB into Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, office-interop

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp).I have successfully installed [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734). However, I just cannot see the choice: "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine" in SSMS during the import (restarted computer as well). I just cannot see what I may have missed. Any ideas? Btw, I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably too late to help you, but in case it helps anyone else, the work-around/solution that worked for me was to use the .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC (with the 32-bit DTSWizard). For setting the data source properties, the simplest thing is to type in the following:

Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<path to mdb/accdb file> -- then you don't have to mess with setting up an ODBC DSN.

Answer (score 0):

Way too late for you but a possibly even easier method is from within access itself, go to "Database Tools" and choose "SQL Server" and you will be presented with the "Upsizing Wizard" which will allow you to convert your database and/or tables to a new or existing SQL Server database.